# How are object locks handled on Spring @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Let's say that the structure of the data is very simple: there are people and dogs, and people can have multiple dogs. Internally, there is a many to many relationship between them.

Given this simple method:

```
@Transactional
public void CreateDog(int personId, string name) {
    Person person = GetPerson(personId);
    Dog dog = new Dog(name, person);
    ...
    dog.setAdoptedDate(now);
    ...
}
```

Is it possible for multiple `CreateDog` to be running concurrently for the same `Person`? Since each dog is independent from each other, it would make sense for there to be no restrictions between the `CreateDog` in the same owner.

How do I know exactly what kind of locking is being applied by @Transactional? Is it possible that it is locking more than it needs, which ends up making the application run worse than it would if the locking was handled manually? This is obviously a very simple example, but one can think of more complicated scenarios where this would be a problem.

My point is that the `Dogs` are independent but the `Persons` might not be. Although they are not independent, they do not collide in this use case so there shouldn't be any problem.

So the question is, is Spring locking `Person` for the whole duration of the method? In that case there is no concurrency for the same person. Is it possible to avoid that?

Comment: Have you read https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html ?

Comment: In short, @Transactional does no locking at the Java level, it just notifies the transaction manager when annotated methods are called/return.